# why does pipebackand always return ANY qtype?

Tags: pipe, powerdns

when sent a query dns to pdns with type equal A , the latter sent to pipe backend using pipe protocl and  qtype always egual ANY  why?i use powerdns 2.9.22 and my os is ubuntu  thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking ANY means PowerDNS will get back all records for that name. This has two important benefits:

1. Any CNAMEs will be spotted, without having to do a separate CNAME query first.
2. If PowerDNS would ask for A, and got back nothing, it would not know whether to respond NXDOMAIN ('name does not exist') or NOERROR ('name exists but there is no A') to the asker. With ANY, if there is no response, it can say NXDOMAIN.

Comment: i understand but if i want to use the qtype for query the db (example select * from table1 where type= qtype  ) using a specified type (example A) what well i do? thank

Comment: you don't. PowerDNS tells the backend what it needs, and the backend should answer :)